# why I get syntax error near "'" so many time?

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module experiment4_experiment4_sch_tb();

// Inputs
   reg Y3;
   reg X3;
   reg Y2;
   reg X2;
   reg Y1;
   reg X1;
   reg Y0;
   reg X0;
   reg Cin;
   reg X4;
   reg Y4;
   reg X5;
   reg Y5;
   reg X6;
   reg Y6;
   reg X7;
   reg Y7;
   reg Cin0;
   reg Cin1;

// Output
   wire 'S0;
   wire 'S1;
   wire 'S2;
   wire 'S3;
   wire 'S4;
   wire 'S5;
   wire 'S6;
   wire 'S7;
   wire 'Cout;
   wire S0;
   wire S1;
   wire S2;
   wire S3;
   wire S4;
   wire S5;
   wire S6;
   wire S7;
   wire Cout;

// Bidirs

// Instantiate the UUT
    experiment4 UUT (
        .'S0('S0), 
        .'S1('S1), 
        .'S2('S2), 
        .'S3('S3), 
        .'S4('S4), 
        .'S5('S5), 
        .'S6('S6), 
        .'S7('S7), 
        .'Cout('Cout), 
        .S0(S0), 
        .S1(S1), 
        .S2(S2), 
        .S3(S3), 
        .S4(S4), 
        .S5(S5), 
        .S6(S6), 
        .S7(S7), 
        .Cout(Cout), 
        .Y3(Y3), 
        .X3(X3), 
        .Y2(Y2), 
        .X2(X2), 
        .Y1(Y1), 
        .X1(X1), 
        .Y0(Y0), 
        .X0(X0), 
        .Cin(Cin), 
        .X4(X4), 
        .Y4(Y4), 
        .X5(X5), 
        .Y5(Y5), 
        .X6(X6), 
        .Y6(Y6), 
        .X7(X7), 
        .Y7(Y7), 
        .Cin0(Cin0), 
        .Cin1(Cin1)
   );
// Initialize Inputs
    initial begin
        Y3 = 1;
        X3 = 1;
        Y2 = 1;
        X2 = 1;
        Y1 = 1;
        X1 = 1;
        Y0 = 1;
        X0 = 1;
        Cin = 0;
        X4 = 1;
        Y4 = 1;
        X5 = 1;
        Y5 = 1;
        X6 = 1;
        Y6 = 1;
        X7 = 1;
        Y7 = 1;
        Cin0 = 0;
        Cin1 = 1;
    end
endmodule
```

Why do I get syntax error near "'" in line 29-37, 52-60? So many line arise same error like this one so Idon't know what is the problem. How can I find what the type of this syntax error is?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a syntax error message so many times because you have so many syntax errors. Just worry about the first one.

```
wire 'S0;
```

is not legal syntax because the `'` does not make any sense.